# Change the casing title of the object inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

An array contains objects with property "title" which contains lower-casing text with `_` . Need to change the title by splitting '_' and need to capitalize first letter after every space .

I can change all the title casing to upper case but I need only the first letter after space should be capitalized

```
  const listData = [
        {
            "title": "some_id",
            "dataTypes": "character varying(65535)"
        },
        {
            "title": "some_value",
            "dataTypes": "character varying(65535)"
        }
  ]
  const newData = []
  listData.map(el => newData.push({"title":el.title.toUpperCase().split('_').join(' '),"dataTypes" : el.dataTypes }))
  console.log(newData);
```

Expected :

```
   const newData = [
        {
            "title": "Some Id",
            "dataTypes": "character varying(65535)"
        },
        {
            "title": "Some Value",
            "dataTypes": "character varying(65535)"
        }
  ]
```

Actual :

```
  const newData = [ 
  { title: 'SOME ID' ,
   dataTypes: 'character varying(65535)' },
  { title: 'SOME VALUE' ,
   dataTypes: 'character varying(65535)' } ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
const listData = [
  {
      "title": "some_id",
      "dataTypes": "character varying(65535)"
  },
  {
      "title": "some_value",
      "dataTypes": "character varying(65535)"
  }
]

const newData = []
listData.map(el => newData.push({
  "title":el.title.split('_').map( word => {
    return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substring(1, word.length);
  }).join(' '),

  "dataTypes" : el.dataTypes }))
console.log(newData);
```

You will have to iterate through the split title and update the first letter.

The result is:

```
[ { title: 'Some Id', dataTypes: 'character varying(65535)' },
  { title: 'Some Value', dataTypes: 'character varying(65535)' } ]
```

Comment: Simple and precise :)

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to implement a captilization function for a `word` as follows:

```
word => `${word.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()}${ word.substring(1)}`
```

This could be integrated with your existing code as shown below:

```js
const listData = [{
    "title": "some_id",
    "dataTypes": "character varying(65535)"
  },
  {
    "title": "some_value",
    "dataTypes": "character varying(65535)"
  }
]

const result = listData.map(item => {
  
  return {
    dataTypes : item.dataTypes,
    title : item.title
        .split('_')
        .map(word => `${word.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()}${ word.substring(1)}`)
        .join(' ')
  }
  
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You were close. The are multiple ways you can capitalize words and one of the ways is using regex which will only capitalize letters.

`"will 101skip that".replace(/\b[a-z]/g, match => match.toUpperCase());`

```
const listData = [
        {
            "title": "some_id",
            "dataTypes": "character varying(65535)"
        },
        {
            "title": "some_value",
            "dataTypes": "character varying(65535)"
        }
  ]
  const newData = []
  listData.map(el => newData.push({"title":el.title.split('_').join(' ').replace(/\b[a-z]/g, match => match.toUpperCase()),"dataTypes" : el.dataTypes }))
  console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish what you are looking for with this...

```js
let newData = listData.map(obj => {
    let newObj = {};
    for (let key in obj) {
        key === 'title' ? newObj[key] = [...obj[key].split('_').map(str => str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1))].join(' ') : newObj[key] = obj[key];
    }
    return newObj;
});
```

...but I would prefer breaking up this code into smaller chunks.
Here I have extracted the logic to *split the string by the underscore and capitalize the end result* into its own function.

```js
function snakeCaseToCapitalize(snake_case) {
  return [...snake_case.split('_').map(str => str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1))].join(' ');
};

let newData = listData.map(obj => {
  let newObj = {};
  for (let key in obj) {
    key === 'title' ? newObj[key] = snakeCaseToCapitalize(obj[key]) : newObj[key] = obj[key];
  }
  return newObj;
});
```

Hopefully that gets you where you want to go!

Comment: This approach also has the added benefit of only requiring knowledge of the key that you need to modify.

Rather than pushing each key specifically to the new array by name, you can simply iterate over all of the keys in the object and only modify the "title" key.

Answer (score 0):

This uses regular expression to do what you need.

```js
const listData = [
        {
            "title": "some_id",
            "dataTypes": "character varying(65535)"
        },
        {
            "title": "some_value",
            "dataTypes": "character varying(65535)"
        }
  ]
  const newData = [];
  listData.map(el => newData.push({"title":(el.title.split('_').join(' ').replace(/\b[a-z](?=[a-z]{1})/g, function(letter) {
return letter.toUpperCase(); } )),"dataTypes" : el.dataTypes }))
  console.log(newData);
```